# How to install a Platform toolset for VC++ 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I want to use Platform Toolset v110, v100 in my VC++ 2013, but the only one I can select is v120. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install Visual Studio 2012 and 2010. They will provide necessary toolsets, such that you'll be able to choose them in VS 2013.